# Replace or Skip Files dialog displayed when copying files

Tags: windows, windows-10

In earlier versions of Windows (XP, 7 and 8.1) when you copy a file to another folder and there is an existing file with the same name, you are presented with a dialog showing file details. This is useful to confirm you are happy to overwrite the destination file and also to catch situations  where you were about to accidentally overwrite a file you wanted to keep.

But in Windows 10 you are presented with a chunky dialog with no helpful information whatsoever.

[image: Replace or Skip Files]

If you click `Compare info for both files` some file details are displayed.

[image: File conflict dialog]

But this is inferior compared with the one displayed in earlier versions. Issues include:

- Information is less detailed
- You must still select the file you want to retain or overwrite. If you forget to, perhaps expecting the overwrite to `Continue` as the button says...nothing happens and you end up not copying the file you want!
- If the source and destination folder names are identical (as in my example), you have **no idea** which box you need to tick.
- There are multiple extra clicks required for each file.

Awful. Is there any way to configure Windows 10 to use the original Windows XP/7/8.1 `Replace or Skip Files` dialog?

Comment: Agreed. Plus the check-buttons are small, making it difficult to click fast though the menu.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to modify the format of the
*Replace or Skip Files* dialog.
Microsoft in its wisdom has decided that too many details are harmful to users,
and there is nothing you can do about it.

If you find the situation unacceptable, your only choice is to use another
file manager or file-copy product.

See these articles :

- [Best Free File Manager](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm)
- [Best Free File Copy Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-copy-utility.htm)

Comment: What a disgrace to simple computing! Im outraged!

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately there is a way without having to use an entirely new File Manager as previously claimed in other answers. A quick google search yielded a small program called **PerigeeCopy** which is lite and easy to configure.

**1.** Get [PerigeeCopy](http://jstanley.pingerthinger.com/pscopy) from the official homepage here. (The software page however doesn’t list Windows 8/8.1/10 in its list of supported OS but it works just on those systems)

**2.** After installing it, launch it from the start menu shortcut – Configure PerigeeCopy. In it settings configure it to replace the Windows Copy Dialog by adding a check mark on the option **Use PerigeeCopy by default for file operations.**

[image]

**PerigeeCopy Settings**

When you add this option it will override the windows copy dialog and use its own. If you don’t want this, you can always use it whenever you want to by clicking using entries it adds in the context menu (PerigeePaste & PerigeeDelete).

[image]

**PerigeeCopy Context Menu Entries**

1. You can also configure it further on how to handle conflicts. If you don’t want a prompt for conflicts, just select Always Overwrite otherwise leave it at Prompt for it to handle conflicts.

[image]

**PerigeeCopy Copy Dialog with File Conflict**

Concerning the auto rename for file conflicts, PerigeeCopy allows you to do that with a one mere button click – **Rename Target**. You also get the **Keep Newer File** button which allows you to replace all files with the same name but skip those that have newer dates/time. So in a way it can come in handy if you synchronize files from different places.

With info from https://www.journeybytes.com/get-old-windows-xp-style-copy-dialog-in/